# ASP .NET Core - How to tell if data contract property was not set or set to null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

In ASP .NET Core, given a controller method for a PATCH endpoint like this:

```cs
[HttpPatch]
[Route("{entity_id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateEntity(
    [FromRoute(Name = "entity_id")]int entity_id,
    [FromBody(Name = "")]EntityUpdate entityUpdate,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken
)
{
    await UpdateEntity(
        entity_id,
        entityUpdate,
        cancellationToken
    );
    return Ok();
}
```

And the following definition for `EntityUpdate`:

```cs
[DataContract(Name = "entity_update")]
public class EntityUpdate 
{
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Is there anyway to tell if a given property of `EntityUpdate` was explicitly set by the client to `null` or simply omitted?

Comment: Wouldnt it technically result in the same outcome anyway?

Comment: I want to add logic that will leave the values in the database untouched when the properties are omitted, but actually set the values in the database to null when the properties are explicitly set to null.

Comment: I would probably add to your question that you're performing a `PATCH` to help clarify.

Comment: Mind adding the definition of `EntityUpdate`?

Comment: An idea would be: a wrapper class like `Omitted<T>` to capsule the omitted or not-omitted logic of your props. The next would be to define a custom model binder that walks the props of type `Omitted<T>` in a model class to set them with a corresponding value depending on if they were explicitly set or not. Ill try to come up with something.

Comment: For identifying whether the field is update, there are two options, one is pointed by @Daneil which is used to add more field to indicate whether the field is update or not, if you change the field value, you need to change the `_nameChanged` field too at client side. For another way, you could try `JsonPatch` which will describe how the client operate the model and apply the changes at server side, you could refer [JsonPatch in ASP.NET Core web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgo the autoproperty and include a `Changed` property.

```
[DataContract(Name = "entity_update")]
public class EntityUpdate 
{
    private string _name;
    private bool _nameChanged;
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get => _name; set { _name = value; _nameChanged = true; } }

    [DataMember(Name = "description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `_nameChanged` would have to be public so the Controller can see it. Maybe `public bool NameChanged { get; private set; }`. Or you could keep a list of changed properties... Lots of ways to do it, but using the property setter to set some kind of flag is the key, as long as the class can be changed.

Comment: yea i ommited some of that detail.

Answer (score -1):

I was hoping that `ModelState` would show you the properties it found, but that only seems to populate anything useful when there are validation errors.

An arguably crude way is to inspect the raw request body for each property name. For example, if the body is JSON, this would look for `"name"` to see if the `Name` property was set:

```
string body;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body)) {
    body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
}

if (body.Contains($"\"{nameof(EntityUpdate.Name)}\"", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) {
    //name was set
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually trying to determine not whether the client sent anything at all, but on a property-by-property basis, whether they sent a value for given properties of `EntityUpdate`.

Comment: I've updated my answer. There might be better ways, but it would work.... But it sounds like Jota might have something a little more elegant.